# How to update a custom image Live Tile every minute in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

There are quite a few Windows Phone 8.1 apps (e.g. Clock hub, Analog Clock Tile, etc.) which allow you to pin an analog clock on the main screen.

I am trying to do the same by following this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff) which shows me how to update an XML document every minute.

But if I am going to create an analog clock tile then it needs to be an image.

I have tried to use `XamlRenderingBackgroundTask` with `RenderTargetBitmap` to generate the image, this bit works. What I am not sure is how can I update this image every minute.

Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the sample you provided and modified it to generate a custom image live tile every minute.

I've tested it on my phone and it seems to be working OK. You might need to do more testing such as memory usage testing to make sure it doesn't go over the cap (maybe can reduce `planTill` to 30 minutes to generate less tiles in the loop?).

**The UserControl xml file `SquareFrontTile1.xml`**

```xml
<Border Height="360" Width="360" Background="#00b2f0" xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' xmlns:mc='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006'>
  <TextBlock Text="{0}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="50.667" />
</Border>
```

**The code**

```cs
public static async void UpdateAsync(BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral)
{
    TileUpdater tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
    IReadOnlyList<ScheduledTileNotification> plannedUpdated = tileUpdater.GetScheduledTileNotifications();

    string language = GlobalizationPreferences.Languages.First();
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime planTill = now.AddHours(1);

    DateTime updateTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0).AddMinutes(1);
    if (plannedUpdated.Count > 0)
        updateTime = plannedUpdated.Select(x => x.DeliveryTime.DateTime).Union(new[] { updateTime }).Max();

    StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("SquareFrontTile1.xml");
    string xml = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    string startXml = string.Format(xml, now.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern));

    XmlDocument tileDocumentNow = await GetTileXmlDocument(startXml);

    TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(tileDocumentNow) { ExpirationTime = now.AddMinutes(1) };
    tileUpdater.Update(notification);

    for (var startPlanning = updateTime; startPlanning < planTill; startPlanning = startPlanning.AddMinutes(1))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(startPlanning);
        Debug.WriteLine(planTill);

        try
        {
            string updateXml = string.Format(xml, startPlanning.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern));
            XmlDocument updatedTileDocument = await GetTileXmlDocument(updateXml);

            ScheduledTileNotification scheduledNotification = new ScheduledTileNotification(updatedTileDocument, new DateTimeOffset(startPlanning)) { ExpirationTime = startPlanning.AddMinutes(1) };
            tileUpdater.AddToSchedule(scheduledNotification);

            Debug.WriteLine("schedule for: " + startPlanning);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    deferral.Complete();
}

private static async Task<XmlDocument> GetTileXmlDocument(string xml)
{
    Border tileUIElement = XamlReader.Load(xml) as Border;
    string liveTileImageName = string.Format("UpdatedLiveTile_{0}.png", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());

    if (tileUIElement != null)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await rtb.RenderAsync(tileUIElement, 150, 150);
        IBuffer pixels = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
        DataReader dReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(pixels);
        byte[] data = new byte[pixels.Length];
        dReader.ReadBytes(data);

        var outputFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFileAsync(liveTileImageName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var outputStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, outputStream);
        enc.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, 150, 150, 96, 96, data);
        await enc.FlushAsync();
    }

    var tileDocument = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);
    var tileImageAttributes = tileDocument.GetElementsByTagName("image");
    XmlElement tmp = tileImageAttributes[0] as XmlElement;
    tmp.SetAttribute("src", liveTileImageName);
    return tileDocument;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
do you have the project you created for download?

Comment: Do you have this project that I could use to modify for an app?

Comment: It was a while ago and I don't have it anymore. But wouldn't the code above enough?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to fully answer the question since I am myself trying to get this working at present. However I will set you in right direction. I have done this in past with windows 8.

What you need to do is create Tile Updater and schedule tiles updates every so often.. in this case one every minute. The tile schema chosen can have be image or text or a combination of both.

you can find the TileSchema catalogue here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

and details of Tile Schema here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212859.aspx

Here is a Windows 8 sample
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/scheduled-notifications-da477093

Here is a snippet from my code which isn't working correctly so far.. tile is blank

```
TileUpdater updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(str2);
ScheduledTileNotification notification2 = new ScheduledTileNotification(document, new DateTimeOffset(time4));
notification2.ExpirationTime = (new DateTimeOffset?((DateTimeOffset)time4.AddMinutes(1.0)));
ScheduledTileNotification notification = notification2;
updater.AddToSchedule(notification);
```

Once I finish this, I will write up a blog post and add a link here

I have created a repro project that tries to do this from within sample app (not background task).
http://1drv.ms/1nai8nn

Comment: I am planning to use content image as opposed to one in iso store.. lets see if it works now.. too many images though

Comment: Good luck with it! I actually thought of the same thing. But then in my case I also need to show the time in digital format, that'd be way too many images to store...

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing 24 x 60 images

Comment: Oh and don't forget square and wide tiles

Comment: @Jessica and Hermit - so you're both making a clock app? :P This basically is the answer to Jessica's question. That's the way to update the tile every minute. Hermit, I guess the xml is not correct? Have you tried using the [NotificationsExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642158.aspx) library? If you share more code I might be able to tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

The sample work for me, I add to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. You must change Notification Services from MPN to WNS in WMAppManifest.xml and add Background task, tick System event, Timer in Package.appxmanifest (Declarations tab).

@Justin XL: your code not work for me, error in line

`Border tileUIElement = XamlReader.Load(xml) as Border;`

Error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

Comment: This is not really the answer to this specific question. The reason that my answer didn't work for you, I guess is because you didn't use XamlRenderingBackgroundTask. Try replacing your IBackgroundTask with it.

Comment: Yes, It's worked. But recommended for use C++ instead of C# for Rendering Xaml in background task.

Comment: That's correct, shouldn't be hard to convert the C# code to C++.